# A collapsible (blog) type menu in django

Tags: django, menu

I am 99% certain that I did not use the correct name but I am trying to find information on how to create a menu that looks and behaves similar to a blog archive menu (just the correct name would already help me look in the right place). Specifically, the ability to click on a top level field and then get all it's children, see the following example:

[image]

My intent is to create such a menu but then using fields from my database where an imaginary entry would be as follows:

```
class foo(models.Model):
    a = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    b = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    c = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

The menu would than show all unique values of `a` as a top level (like the year in the example) and clicking on it would show all unique `b` values (like month in the example), clicking that would list all individual corresponding entries.

I would prefer the correct name for such a menu and if possible some documentation/guide on how a similar concept would be created using django.

Comment: you would need a `DateTimeField`  in your `foo`model and then group your queryset by year and month

Comment: @Tushortz I am trying to group them by text strings and not by time (the picture just illustrated the type of menu that I want to create). For example `acid` or `base` as top level menu items.

Comment: In this case, you would loop through your model fields and get the uniques of whatever field to represent your text strings you want to use to group.`

Comment: @Tushortz Thank you so far, I am slowly getting there :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to get this working using some bootstrap and django.

The view was generated so that it was a list of querysets as follows (with the `enzyme_activity_type=types.values()[0]` being the only bit that I don't like:

```
class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'gts/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'latest_enzyme_list'

    def get_queryset(self):
        try:
            resultList = []
            for types in Enzymes.objects.values('enzyme_activity_type').distinct():                 
                 resultList.append(Enzymes.objects.filter(enzyme_activity_type=types.values()[0]))
            return resultList
        except:
            return Enzymes.objects.none()
```

The html template using the queryset and bootstrap (the relevant bits for bootstrap and javascript are in the base.html):

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block body %}

<div class="section" id="s-module-django.db.models.fields">
    <h1 class="page-header text-primary">Glycoenzymes for Bioindustries</h1>   
    <div>
        <p>Complete list of all enzymes in the database:</p>
    </div>

    {% if latest_enzyme_list %}
        <ul>
        {% for enzyme_type in latest_enzyme_list %}
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" href="#{{enzyme_type.first.enzyme_activity_type|cut:" "}}">
                    {{enzyme_type.first.enzyme_activity_type}}
                </button>
            </div>
            <div id="{{enzyme_type.first.enzyme_activity_type|cut:" "}}" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            {% for enzyme in enzyme_type %}
                <div><a href="{% url 'gts:detail' enzyme.id %}"><li>{{ enzyme.barcode  }}</li></a></div>
            {% endfor %}
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    {% else %}
        <p>No enzymes are available.</p>
    {% endif %}
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

Excerpt from the base.html (to illustrate the bootstrap inclusion):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}"/>
</head>
<body>
  {% block body %}
  {% endblock %}

<!------- Bootstrap + JQuery JS---------> 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="{% static 'scripts/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script> 

</body>
</html>
```

This results in the following picture (with the first item 'activated'):

[image]

Please post a comment if the way I fixed it should be altered in any way to be correct Django programming.